# How to simulate different bluetooth devices in one application?

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, simulation

I want to develop an Android application which can simulate different Bluetooth devices in one.
for example on launching this application my android device or Computer system act at Bluetooth watch to other devices.

The closest solution I found is a IOS application by Attack pattern .com
http://attackpattern.com/work/bluetooth/

I tried to develop the similar application in android or LINUX system but not find any solution.
Please help.

Comment: Androids bluetooth is very limited compared to Apples, but on top of  that it likely took a pretty good team to implement the full functionality of attackpattern